# Thermodynamic limits to photovoltaic or photochemical processes

Tags: thermodynamics, photons, solar-cells

Photovoltaic or photochemical (photosynthesis) processes are basically extracting energy from the temperature difference between the Sun and Earth. In practice they are only able to capture photons in rather narrow range of energies, so their efficiency is rather low. But assuming we found a way to capture most of the spectrum, what is theoretical limit of the process?

A solar powerplant using heating of a medium is limited by the Carnot cycle efficiency, but photovoltaic process does not seem to involve any cycle. So does it allow, theoretically, achieving higher efficiency?

Comment: If the following link is correct, it appears that a Carnot efficiency of 95% would constitute the maximum theoretical upper limit for all solar converters. https://www.intechopen.com/books/solar-cells-new-approaches-and-reviews/theoretical-calculation-of-the-efficiency-limit-for-solar-cells

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_efficiency_limit is a starting place

Comment: That all basically states that yes, the thermodynamic limit applies, but without any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate thermodynamic limit for solar energy conversion is ~93% and is known as the [Landsberg limit](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.328187),

$$
1 - \frac{4}{3}\frac{T}{T_s} + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{T}{T_s}\right)^4 \approx 93\%
$$

named after P. T. Landsberg. Where $T$ is the temperature of the converter and $T_s$ is the temperature of the source.

There is a nice [review article](https://www.pnas.org/content/115/16/E3609) here about the limits of different approaches.

The Carnot limit,

$$
1-\frac{T}{T_s} \approx 95\%
$$

goes give a higher value but it is **unattainable** because [it does not consider the light emitted back to sun as waste](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.573.6314&rep=rep1&type=pdf).